# Change icons in SP2013 online (365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, office-365

Is it possible to change the icons used in various places? I've made some major changes to the look and feel and whilst the icons look great the colours don't go with my background colours.

I've identified the spcommon.png file is the image the sites uses but I have no way of replacing that as its placed in the "_layouts" folder.

Is there another method of doing this?

For instance...the + icon is made up of the following

```
<span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20">
   <img src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" class="ms-list-addnew-img20"/>
</span>
```

We can't change the SRC to we need to suppress that style then add a background image to the span. Its difficult to replicate the way it currently works i.e. use the spcommon.png or even your own version. Having to work out the X,Y coords for the bg image is a pain!

Cheers,

S

Answer (score 3):

You could use the build-in design manager introduced in SP2013. Through this you can add a custom masterpage and in it place references to custom CSS files which you have to place in the Style Library.

[Here's a guide which should get you started.](http://rstagg.com/2013/04/17/office-365-branding-creating-a-custom-masterpage-for-your-office-365-public-facing-website/)

Comment: Yeah i already have my own custom master page and CSS but i want to override the spcommon.png or at least specify my own one..thanks for the input though.

Comment: It's not possible to override it, but nothings stopping you in uploading your own spcommon.png to the Style Library and using it in your CSS files to override 365 SharePoint's CSS classes with your own spcommon.png as `background-image`.

Comment: yeah thats kinda what I've done but the + icon for instance is a img with a SRC to the spcommon and a class which is hard to mimic with CSS. Updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think so, all of the images as well as for example the xml defining document icons are placed in `_layouts`.

I guess javascript is an option, but not a very pratical one.

Comment: agreed...there is a way to do it in CSS which I've done by using my own image for icons and overriding the CSS that displays the default image. But i feel its a bit clumsy and wondered if there was a better way. Thanks for input.